# And/Or controller combinaton

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Hey I have a quick question that has been bothering me; when I use logic bricks, I use (for example) the following: Keyboard > And > Action. I have a setup for WASD where I use an *or* controller for multiple combinations. My issue is, I need to have my character walk holding his arm out if he has a gun, and keeping his hands down when not. So, when my property *"weapons active"* is on (assuming player has a weapon), he should walk with his arms out, and not when property is off. I need to have an or controller for WASD and an and controller for if the property is on, as in, I need the walk animation to be triggered when either WASD is pressed AND the property is on. How do I use an and and an or controller on one event in logic bricks?

Comment: Why can't you just use an AND controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured a simple solution, and would like to help anyone who has had this issue. Just have a property that is toggled when you use WSAD; and have a second event where you need the property to be set to 1; as well as the other property.